# Sending data to sqlite from beautifulsoup on scraperwiki but getting KeyError: 'href'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn Python and Beautiful Soup by using ScraperWiki. I want a list of all the kickstarter projects in Edmonton.

I have successfully scraped the page I am looking for and pulled out the data I want. I am having trouble getting that data formatted and exported to the database.

Console output:

```
Line 42 - url = link["href"]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py:879 -- __getitem__((self=<h2 class="bbcard_nam...more

KeyError: 'href'
```

Code:

```
import scraperwiki
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_page ="http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/search?term=edmonton"
html = scraperwiki.scrape(search_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

max = soup.find("p", { "class" : "blurb" }).get_text()
num = int(max.split(" ")[0])

if num % 12 != 0:
    last_page = int(num/12) + 1
else:
    last_page = int(num/12)

for n in range(1, last_page + 1):
    html = scraperwiki.scrape(search_page + "&page=" + str(n))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    projects = soup.find_all("h2", { "class" : "bbcard_name" })
    counter = (n-1)*12 + 1
    print projects

    for link in projects:
        url = link["href"]
        data = {"URL": url, "id": counter}
#save into the data store, giving the unique parameter
        scraperwiki.sqlite.save(["URL"],data)
        counter+=1
```

There are anchors with `href` in projects. How can I get the URL from each `<h2>` element in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're asking for `<h2>` tags, so that's what BeautifulSoup is giving you. None of these will have `href` attributes, obviously, because headers can't have `href` attributes.

Saying `for link in projects` merely gives each item in `projects` (which are level-2 headers) the *name* `link`, it doesn't magically *turn them into* links.

At the risk of seeming insultingly obvious, if you want links, look for `<a>` tags instead...? Or perhaps you want all the links *inside* each header... e.g.

```
for project in projects:
   for link in project.find_all("a"):
```

Or maybe do away with finding the projects and go straight for the links in the first place:

```
for link in soup.select("h2.bbcard_name a"):
```

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for the links in the h2.

`<h2 class="bbcard_name"><a href="/projects/1433240860/salute-to-50-edmonton-opera-chorus-in-concert?ref=search">Salute to 50: Edmonton Opera Chorus in concert</a><span>by Edmonton Opera </span></h2>`

So I am calling up the h2s but I want to get the links inside of them.

Comment: Thank you. Your first response worked. 

I was looking for the links inside each header. Not insultingly obvious at all. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `href` attribute in `<h2>` tags.

This piece of code:

```
for link in projects:
```

iterates through `projects`, which contains `<h2>` tags, not links.

I'm not so clear on what do you want, but i assume you want to find the `href` attribute  of `<a>` tags inside `<h2>` tags, try this one:

```
data = {"URL":[], "id":counter}
for header in projects: #take the header)
    links = header.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        url = link["href"]
```

Also, `data = {"URL": url, "id": counter}` overwrites the dictionary `data` on each loop. So change it to this:

```
data["URL"].append(url) # store it on this format {'URL':[link1,link2,link3]}
```

Comment: Thank you! the data overwriting was happening as well. Your answer cleared that up for me. Thanks so much.